# how do i check the status of nginx on mac

Tags: macos, nginx

I have a work computer that's a mac, and I am not really used to it yet.

I'm trying to just find a command to check the status of Nginx, to see if it is running or not.

I have tried :

```bash
$ sudo systemctl config nginx
$ sudo service nginx status
```

and a few other random variations.

like just `nginx status`. or `sudo nginx help`

But none of them doesn't seem to work.

Would appreciate any answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `launchctl list` to list the information about the services running on your machine. Look for nginx and take note of its PID.

Then based it's PID, you can checks the currently running nginx processes and their status with: `launchctl print pid/<pid-of-nginx>`